# What is the right way to put objects to boost::property_tree?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

Consider following example:

```
#include <boost\property_tree\ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

typedef boost::property_tree::ptree PT;

struct Foo
{
    int bar;
    int egg;
    Foo(): bar(), egg() {}
};


int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar = 5;
    PT pt;
    pt.put<Foo>("foo", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to boost and I'm willing to put a Foo object into property tree. The example above will not compile giving an error:

`c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/boost/property_tree/stream_translator.hpp:33:13: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 's << e'`

Can anyone suggest the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create an overloaded `operator<<` for your `Foo` object-type.  This can be done by creating a function that takes the members of your `Foo` object-type, and passes them via the `operator<<` to a `ostream` object-type.  Here is a very simple example:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Foo output_object)
{
    out << egg << " " << bar;
    return out;
}
```

This works because the `int` types you are using as the members of your `Foo` object-type are calling the overloaded version of `operator<<` for `ostream` and `int`.  So if the objects that are part of your `Foo` type are not already overloaded, then you would also have to create overloaded `operator<<` functions for those types as well.

Once this is done, your code can be called anywhere like so:

```
Foo test;
cout << test; //will print out whatever the values of "egg" and "bar" are
```

Additionally, any other code that attemps to use `operator<<` with an `ostream` object and your `Foo` type as operands will function correctly as well.

Finally, you can either `inline` the overloaded function and place it in a header-file, or you can create the function declaration in a header, and then define the function in a code module somewhere else.

Comment: So, what exactly are you supposed to do if you have operator<< overloaded with `std::ostream`s for some other purpose with this object? Like if the format you store in the `property_tree` should look different than what you use to print it for display purposes?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Was there another option that I'm missing? I don't see a way that you can overload `operator<<` twice for std::ostream, one for the specific instance in the `boost::property_tree`, and another for `std::cout`, etc.  The only thing I could think of is to either investigate if there is some type of derived class that `boost::property_tree` is using for I/O that you can use to create a more specific overload of `operator<<`.  Otherwise you could possibly wrap `std::cout` in another class, and overload `operator<<` for your `Foo` class and the `std::cout` wrapper.  Any other options?